# How to perform model diagnostics with flexsurvreg?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I would like to use parametric survival models assuming a Gompertz distribution using the `flexsurv` package in R to quantify associations in biomedical research. However, to my knowledge, there is no build-in function, like the `residuals.survreg` contained within the `survival` package, to extract residuals allowing one to perform model diagnostics (i.e., verifying the proportionality of hazards assumption, identity influential or outlying cases etc.)

Are there ways to ascertain proportionality of hazards and to appraise the presence of influential cases, outliers, correct covariate functional form and so forth using the following example:

```
require(flexsurv)

# No scientific notation
options(scipen = 999)

# Use the breast cancer data contained within the flexsurv package
d <- bc

# Fit a parametric survival model with Gompertz distrubution
fit <- flexsurvreg(Surv(rectime,censrec==1) ~ group, dist = "gompertz", 
data = d)
fit
```

Comment: The package appears focused on **model-fitting** rather than diagnostics. The output from `str(fit)` and `methods(class="flexsurvreg")` doesn't look too promising. I'm not aware of another package implementing this. See also:
  [1]: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231303/testing-proportional-hazards-assumption-in-parametric-models